# Invoke function present inside component from spec.ts file in angular 8

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I am new in writing Angular test cases using Jasmine, I am trying to invoke a function `getRoleModulePermissionById(event,id)` from `manage-permissions.component.spec.ts` which is inside `manage-permissions.component.ts`

**Manage Permission Component:**

```
getRoleModulePermissionById(event,id) {
        this. moduleNameStr = event.target.innerText
        console.log("this. moduleNameStr",this. moduleNameStr)
        console.log("id-----------------",id,);
        this.moduleId=id;
        this.roleService.getRoleModulePermission(id).subscribe(
            (response) => {
                this.isShow = true;
                this.getHide = true;
                this.roleList = response;
                console.log('inside get ' + JSON.stringify(this.roleList))
            },
            (httpErrorRes) => {
                alert(constants.roleModuleNotFound);
            }
        );
        this.prepareBreadcrumb();
    }
```

**Manage Permissions Spec:**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { constants } from '../../../shared/static/constants';
import { ModuleServiceService } from '../../services/module-service.service';

import { ManagePermissionsComponent } from './manage-permissions.component';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

// mock the service
class MockModuleservice extends ModuleServiceService {
    // mock everything used by the component
  };

describe('ManagePermissionsComponent', () => {
  let component: ManagePermissionsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ManagePermissionsComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [RouterTestingModule,HttpClientTestingModule],
      declarations: [ ManagePermissionsComponent ],
      providers: [{
        provide: ModuleServiceService ,
        useClass: MockModuleservice
      }]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ManagePermissionsComponent);
    component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create manage-permission', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should able to getRoleModulePermissionById', () => {
    component.getRoleModulePermissionById(null,1);
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  })

});
```

I am not able to figured out, how to invoke function,as instance of `ManagePermissionsComponent` has already been created in `beforEach()` . I am trying to prepare the code coverage report,so I want to cover the entire lines of code inside the function `getRoleModulePermissionById`, but not able to do so

Kindly correct me If I am doing something wrong, also provide me the Jasmine best practice guide.

**Karma.conf.js file**

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      jasmine: {
        // you can add configuration options for Jasmine here
        // the possible options are listed at https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Configuration.html
        // for example, you can disable the random execution with `random: false`
        // or set a specific seed with `seed: 4321`
      },
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    jasmineHtmlReporter: {
      suppressAll: true // removes the duplicated traces
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../../coverage'),
      subdir: '.',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'html' },
        { type: 'text-summary' }
      ]
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

Comment: component.getRoleModulePermissionById(null,1); this should invoke that function. What is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a couple of things for the lines to get covered in the report.

1. Cover the lines which are not in subscribe() function
2. Cover the lines which are in subscribe() function.

Please do the following:

```
@Injectable()
class MockRoleService extends RoleService {
  getRoleModulePermission(): any {
    const mockData = {} // Fill the type of response here
    return of(mockData); // Import 'of' from 'rxjs'
  }
}

// Add this in the providers: 

// Add a service mocker here;
let roleService: RoleService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [RouterTestingModule,HttpClientTestingModule],
      declarations: [ ManagePermissionsComponent ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ModuleServiceService ,
          useClass: MockModuleservice
        },
        {
          provide: RoleService ,
          useClass: MockRoleService
        }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });
roleService = TestBed.get(RoleService); <-- this line is important to mock API Failure scenario

// Now the test cases: 

// HTTP Success scenarios
it('should run the #getRoleModulePermissionById() + success response of subscribe', () => {
   spyOn(component, 'getRoleModulePermissionById').and.callThrough();
   const event = {
     target: {
       innerText: 'someInnerText'
     }
   };
   component.getRoleModulePermissionById(event, 'someId');
   expect(component.getRoleModulePermissionById).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

// HTTP Failure error scenario
it('should run #getRoleModulePermissionById() method, API-Failure scenario', () => {
   const errorResponse = { status: 500 };
   spyOn(roleService, 'getRoleModulePermission').and.returnValue(throwError(errorResponse));
   spyOn(component, 'getRoleModulePermissionById').and.callThrough();
   const event = {
     target: {
       innerText: 'someInnerText'
     }
   };
   component.getRoleModulePermissionById(event, 'someId');
   expect(component.getRoleModulePermissionById).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

These 2 test cases should cover both the scenarios perfectly.

Comment: Srikar, Thanks for the replying.
I have tried your solution but now code coverage report itself is not generating. When i perform undo action code coverage report generated, not able to figure out what went wrong

Comment: These test cases are not causing the generation of report to be a problem. Something else is happening. Is the karma browser opening? If so are you getting any console errors? If so paste them Otherwise, its a bigger issue and we have to see what is happening. Try adding the whole code into a stackblitz or something and we can see if we can reproduce the issue there. Then we can handle things accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock the role service correctly and return the mock response in your test case to test the subscribe block, In jasmine this is how we create a stub:

```
  const roleServiceStub = jasmine.createSpyObj('RoleService', ['getRoleModulePermission']);
```

and then you will need to provide this service to your test Angular module, like this:

```
{ provide: RoleService, useValue: roleServiceStub }
```

Here is the complete test for subscribe block and error block:

```
describe('ManagePermissionsComponent', () => {
    let component: ManagePermissionsComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ManagePermissionsComponent>;
    const roleServiceStub = jasmine.createSpyObj('RoleService', ['getRoleModulePermission']);


    beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
            declarations: [ManagePermissionsComponent],
            providers: [{
                provide: ModuleServiceService,
                useClass: MockModuleservice
            }, { provide: RoleService, useValue: roleServiceStub },]
        })
            .compileComponents();
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ManagePermissionsComponent);
        component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create manage-permission', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should able to getRoleModulePermissionById', () => {
        const mockRoleResponse = {

        }; // Keep is as your response
        roleServiceStub.getRoleModulePermission.and.returnValue(of(mockRoleResponse));
        component.getRoleModulePermissionById(null, 1);
        expect(component.roleList).toBeTruthy();
        // Write other assertion based on your mock respone
    });

    it('should handle error', () => {
        const mockRoleResponse = {

        }; // Keep is as your response

        spyOn(window, 'alert');
        roleServiceStub.getRoleModulePermission.and.returnValue(throwError({ error: 'some error'));
        component.getRoleModulePermissionById(null, 1);
        expect(window.alert).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});
```

Comment: Ritesh, Thanks for the replying.
I have tried your solution but now code coverage report itself is not generating. When i perform undo action code coverage report generated, not able to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Did all test cases pass? Show me your karma.conf file.

Comment: Please see my edits and kindly suggest me the solution.

Comment: Could you please open a discussion chat I have a lot of queries about angular unit testing?

Comment: You don't seem to have HTML reports configured.

Comment: How your reports look like?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more. actually i am not getting properly that you are talking about which report. I have a index.html in coverage folder. Would you mean by that report?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236236/discussion-between-aparna-bhargav-and-ritesh-waghela).